# Limit points on map plot to one layer

Tags: r, ggplot2, spatial

Given the following map:

```
library(data.table)
library(ggplot2)
data.table
test <- data.table(x=c(-89, -85), y=c(40, 35))

state <-as.data.table(map_data("state"))

ggplot() +
  geom_polygon(data=state[region=="illinois"], aes(x=long, y=lat, group=group)) +
  geom_point(data=test, aes(x=x, y=y), col="blue")
```

Is there a simple way to restrict the plotting of the points in the `test` data.table so that only the ones within the limits of the `geom_polygon` layer show on the map?

Cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `in.out` function from the `mgcv` package to select only points that are inside a polygon. You can use this to plot only points inside the boundaries of Illinois. The example below adds an extra point that's within the rectangle that bounds Illinois, but that is not within the borders of Illinois.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(mgcv)

test <- data.frame(lat=c(40, 35, 39), long=c(-89, -85, -91))

state = map_data("state")

# Limit points only to those inside Illinois
point.filter = in.out(as.matrix(state[state$region=="illinois", c("lat","long")]), 
                      as.matrix(test))

ggplot() +
  geom_polygon(data=state[state$region=="illinois", ], 
               aes(x=long, y=lat, group=group), fill="white", color="black") +
  geom_point(data=test[point.filter, ], aes(x=long, y=lat), col="blue") +
  geom_point(data=test, aes(x=long, y=lat), col="red", pch=1, size=3) +
  coord_map(xlim=range(state[state$region=="illinois",]$long), 
            ylim=range(state[state$region=="illinois",]$lat))
```

[image]

You can use `in.out` to test whether each of a set of points is inside at least one of several polygons (e.g., multiple states), but in that case, each polygon has to be separated by a row of `NA`. Here's an example where we test whether a set of points is inside the contiguous 48 United States, but using the `state` data frame, which has a separate polygon for each state. I've added two points that aren't inside the U.S. for this illustration:

```
library(dplyr) # For bind_rows() function

# Add an NA row between each state
tmp=lapply(split(state[,c("lat","long","region")], state$region), function(x) {
  bind_rows(list(x, data.frame(region=NA, lat=NA, long=NA)))
})
tmp = bind_rows(tmp)

# Points for testing
test <- data.frame(lat=c(40, 35, 39, -10, 20), long=c(-89, -85, -91, -89, 0))

point.filter = in.out(as.matrix(tmp[, c("lat","long")]), 
                      as.matrix(test))

point.filter
```

> ```
> [1]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
> ```

Comment: Wasn't me. Anyway, thanks for the answer! I was hoping the solution would be simpler but this will get the job done.